# Hibernate & SQLite3, One to many relationship mapping

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, sqlite, one-to-many

I am trying to create a one to many relationship with Hibernate 5.3 and SQLite3

Here is my user entity which have an unidirectional one to many relation with category entity.

**User**

```
package fr.voidwork.rssflow.model;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;

import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;

/**
Buisness object that represent a user in the system
*/
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="increment")
    @GenericGenerator(name="increment", strategy = "increment")
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Category> categories;

    public User() {

    }

    public Long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return this.email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return this.password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public List<Category> getCategories() {
        return this.categories;
    }

    public void setCategories(List<Category> categories) {
        this.categories = categories;
    }
}
```

**Category**

```
package fr.voidwork.rssflow.model;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;

import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;

/**
Buisness object that represent the user categories of flows
*/
@Entity
@Table(name = "categories")
public class Category {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="increment")
    @GenericGenerator(name="increment", strategy = "increment")
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "icon")
    private String icon;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Category> subCategories;


    public Category() {

    }

    public Long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getIcon() {
        return this.icon;
    }

    public void setIcon(String icon) {
        this.icon = icon;
    }

    public List<Category> getSubCategories() {
        return this.subCategories;
    }

    public void setSubCategories(List<Category> subCategories) {
        this.subCategories = subCategories;
    }
}
```

When I run the maven test phase I get this output

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running fr.voidwork.rssflow.AppTest
Nov 27, 2018 7:15:16 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.7.Final}
Nov 27, 2018 7:15:16 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector (file:/C:/Users/Florent/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-impl/2.3.0/jaxb-impl-2.3.0.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Nov 27, 2018 7:15:16 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.4.Final}
Nov 27, 2018 7:15:16 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Nov 27, 2018 7:15:16 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [org.sqlite.JDBC] at URL [jdbc:sqlite:test.db]
Nov 27, 2018 7:15:16 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {password=****, user=}
Nov 27, 2018 7:15:16 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
Nov 27, 2018 7:15:16 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
Nov 27, 2018 7:15:17 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect
Nov 27, 2018 7:15:17 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.LobCreatorBuilderImpl useContextualLobCreation
INFO: HHH000423: Disabling contextual LOB creation as JDBC driver reported JDBC version [2] less than 4
Hibernate:

    drop table if exists categories
Nov 27, 2018 7:15:17 PM org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl getIsolatedConnection
INFO: HHH10001501: Connection obtained from JdbcConnectionAccess [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess@370c1968] for (non-JTA) DDL execution was not in auto-commit mode; the Connection 'local transaction' will be committed and the Connection will be set into auto-commit mode.
Hibernate:

    drop table if exists categories_categories
Hibernate:

    drop table if exists users
Hibernate:

    drop table if exists users_categories
Hibernate:

    create table categories (
       id bigint not null,
        icon varchar(255),
        name varchar(255),
        primary key (id)
    )
Nov 27, 2018 7:15:17 PM org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl getIsolatedConnection
INFO: HHH10001501: Connection obtained from JdbcConnectionAccess [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess@6deee370] for (non-JTA) DDL execution was not in auto-commit mode; the Connection 'local transaction' will be committed and the Connection will be set into auto-commit mode.
Hibernate:

    create table categories_categories (
       Category_id bigint not null,
        subCategories_id bigint not null
    )
Hibernate:

    create table users (
       id bigint not null,
        email varchar(255),
        password varchar(255),
        primary key (id)
    )
Hibernate:

    create table users_categories (
       User_id bigint not null,
        categories_id bigint not null
    )
Hibernate:

    alter table categories_categories
       add constraint UK_rl0t2o27151jl3ag0vkd1klc1 unique (subCategories_id)
Nov 27, 2018 7:15:17 PM org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl handleException
WARN: GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "
    alter table categories_categories
       add constraint UK_rl0t2o27151jl3ag0vkd1klc1 unique (subCategories_id)" via JDBC Statement
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "
    alter table categories_categories
       add constraint UK_rl0t2o27151jl3ag0vkd1klc1 unique (subCategories_id)" via JDBC Statement
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlString(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:440)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:424)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.createFromMetadata(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:349)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.performCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:166)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:135)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:121)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:155)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:310)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:467)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:708)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
        at fr.voidwork.rssflow.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:17)
        at fr.voidwork.rssflow.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:12)
        at fr.voidwork.rssflow.AppTest.shouldAnswerWithTrue(AppTest.java:22)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
Caused by: org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near "constraint": syntax error)
        at org.sqlite.core.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:941)
        at org.sqlite.core.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:953)
        at org.sqlite.core.DB.throwex(DB.java:918)
        at org.sqlite.core.NativeDB.prepare_utf8(Native Method)
        at org.sqlite.core.NativeDB.prepare(NativeDB.java:134)
        at org.sqlite.core.DB.prepare(DB.java:257)
        at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Statement.execute(JDBC3Statement.java:52)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54)
        ... 44 more

Hibernate:

    alter table users_categories
       add constraint UK_r4eblpqse9gr5189y0fl3olyq unique (categories_id)
Nov 27, 2018 7:15:17 PM org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl handleException
WARN: GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "
    alter table users_categories
       add constraint UK_r4eblpqse9gr5189y0fl3olyq unique (categories_id)" via JDBC Statement
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "
    alter table users_categories
       add constraint UK_r4eblpqse9gr5189y0fl3olyq unique (categories_id)" via JDBC Statement
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlString(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:440)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:424)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.createFromMetadata(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:349)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.performCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:166)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:135)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:121)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:155)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:310)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:467)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:708)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
        at fr.voidwork.rssflow.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:17)
        at fr.voidwork.rssflow.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:12)
        at fr.voidwork.rssflow.AppTest.shouldAnswerWithTrue(AppTest.java:22)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
Caused by: org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near "constraint": syntax error)
        at org.sqlite.core.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:941)
        at org.sqlite.core.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:953)
        at org.sqlite.core.DB.throwex(DB.java:918)
        at org.sqlite.core.NativeDB.prepare_utf8(Native Method)
        at org.sqlite.core.NativeDB.prepare(NativeDB.java:134)
        at org.sqlite.core.DB.prepare(DB.java:257)
        at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Statement.execute(JDBC3Statement.java:52)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54)
        ... 44 more

Nov 27, 2018 7:15:17 PM org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl applyImportSources
INFO: HHH000476: Executing import script 'org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ScriptSourceInputNonExistentImpl@6add8e3f'
Hibernate:
    select
        max(id)
    from
        users
Hibernate:
    insert
    into
        users
        (email, password, id)
    values
        (?, ?, ?)
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.751 sec

Results :

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  4.116 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-11-27T19:15:17+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

It seems like there is a syntax error with these queries

```
alter table users_categories
       add constraint UK_r4eblpqse9gr5189y0fl3olyq unique (categories_id)

alter table categories_categories
       add constraint UK_rl0t2o27151jl3ag0vkd1klc1 unique (subCategories_id)
```

running these queries in the sqlite3 shell gives me a syntax error to :

```
Error: near "constraint": syntax error
```

but I have no idea how to fix it.

Here is my POM

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>fr.voidwork.rssflow</groupId>
  <artifactId>rssflow-model-hibernate</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <url>https://gitlab.voidwork.fr/rssflow/rssflow-model-hibernate</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

    <repositories>
      <!-- For hibernate5 sqlite3 dialect -->
      <repository>
          <id>jitpack.io</id>
          <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
      </repository>
  </repositories>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.xerial/sqlite-jdbc -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
      <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
      <version>3.25.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
      <version>5.3.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-impl -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.dialect/sqlite-dialect -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.gwenn</groupId>
      <artifactId>sqlite-dialect</artifactId>
      <version>master</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>

      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

and my hibernate config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="format_sql">true</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.sqlite.JDBC</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:sqlite:test.db</property>
        <property name="connection.username"></property>
        <property name="connection.password"></property>

        <!-- Change for production context -->
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <!-- Database schema update -->
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

        <!-- Mapping -->
        <mapping class="fr.voidwork.rssflow.model.User"/>
        <mapping class="fr.voidwork.rssflow.model.Category"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: Seems like SQLite don't support some features like these  https://www.sqlite.org/omitted.html . Only the RENAME TABLE and ADD COLUMN variants of the ALTER TABLE command are supported !!

Comment: Since ALTER TABLE is not fully supported by SQLite it's better to have a hand made database than using hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = create. So you should create tables using sql statements first and set hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto to validate in order to check if the tables you created are corresponding to your hibernate mapping.